# Finding the domain of $f(x) = \frac{2}{4-\sqrt{9-x^2}}$.

Tags: functions

Finding the domain of $f(x) = \frac{2}{4-\sqrt{9-x^2}}$, how can I deal with the denominator, I have to take into account 2 things:
1- the denominator not equal zero.
2-the value under the square root must be greater than or equal to zero.
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: The domain of that $f(x)$ is whatever you say it is.  It could be empty or all real numbers or a bitfield.  What you are probably intending to ask is "which real numbers, when $f$ is applied to them, also result in a real number?"

Comment: Um..... the denominator can't be equal to zero, and the value under the square root must be greater than or equal to zero.  What possible *more* help could you possibly need?

Comment: thank you so much @fleablood I do not need anymore help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct (if $f$ is  a real-valued function). So you need both of those conditions to hold (if the function is real-valued).
The conditions are
$$4-\sqrt{9-x^2} \neq 0$$

**and**

$$9-x^2 \geq 0.$$

Can you go from here?

(Note that the domain is just the set of numbers that are inputted into the function. This can be chosen freely, so I think you wanted the domain such that $f$ is real-valued)

Comment: yes I wanted the domain such that f is real-valued, but I do not know exactly what to do after taking into account the two conditions mentioned, How can I combine these 2 conditions?

Comment: If you solve the two conditions for $x$, you get  
$$x^2 \neq -7$$  
and   
$$x^2 \leq 9 \implies -3\leq x\leq 3.$$.  
  
If $f$ is real-valued, then the first condition tells us that you have to take real values of $x$.  
The second condition tells us that $-3\leq x\leq 3$.  
Combining them you get the domain of $x$ to be
the real numbers $x$ such that $-3\leq x \leq 3$.